# Javascript extract value

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm using weather-js with this code :

```
weather.find({search: 'San Francisco, CA', degreeType: 'F'}, function(err, result) {
  if(err) console.log(err);

  console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 2));
});
```

But I don't know how I could extract the result value from this

Comment: "I don't know how I could extract the result value" -- I don't know what you mean

Comment: I want a var that contain "result" outside of this, the console.log will be removed.

Answer (score 0):

The result should be like this:

```
[
  {
    "location": {
      "name": "San Francisco, CA",
      "lat": "37.777",
      "long": "-122.42",
      "timezone": "-7",
      "alert": "",
      "degreetype": "F",
      "imagerelativeurl": "http://blob.weather.microsoft.com/static/weather4/en-us/"
    },
    "current": {
      "temperature": "70",
      "skycode": "32",
      "skytext": "Sunny",
      "date": "2017-03-14",
      "observationtime": "13:15:00",
      "observationpoint": "San Francisco, California",
      "feelslike": "70",
      "humidity": "59",
      "winddisplay": "3 mph West",
      "day": "Tuesday",
      "shortday": "Tue",
      "windspeed": "3 mph",
      "imageUrl": "http://blob.weather.microsoft.com/static/weather4/en-us/law/32.gif"
    },
    "forecast": [
      {
        "low": "52",
        "high": "69",
        "skycodeday": "31",
        "skytextday": "Clear",
        "date": "2017-03-13",
        "day": "Monday",
        "shortday": "Mon",
        "precip": ""
      },
      {
        "low": "52",
        "high": "70",
        "skycodeday": "34",
        "skytextday": "Mostly Sunny",
        "date": "2017-03-14",
        "day": "Tuesday",
        "shortday": "Tue",
        "precip": "10"
      },
      {
        "low": "56",
        "high": "63",
        "skycodeday": "26",
        "skytextday": "Cloudy",
        "date": "2017-03-15",
        "day": "Wednesday",
        "shortday": "Wed",
        "precip": "20"
      },
      {
        "low": "50",
        "high": "64",
        "skycodeday": "28",
        "skytextday": "Mostly Cloudy",
        "date": "2017-03-16",
        "day": "Thursday",
        "shortday": "Thu",
        "precip": "10"
      },
      {
        "low": "53",
        "high": "67",
        "skycodeday": "32",
        "skytextday": "Sunny",
        "date": "2017-03-17",
        "day": "Friday",
        "shortday": "Fri",
        "precip": "10"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

In the result, there are many useful information:

- latitude & longitude of the location
- current temperature of the location
- forecast information for next four days

All those information exist in the result JSON that you can parse and use it. Consider that the result is an JSON array with only one element in this case.
for example you can log current temperature like this:

```
console.log(result[0].current.temperature)
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare a variable and write the result into this variable, if no error occured:

```
var res = null;
weather.find({search: 'San Francisco, CA', degreeType: 'F'}, function(err, result) {
  if(err) {
    console.log(err);
  } else {
    res = result;
  }

  console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 2));
});
```